# How do I use javascript to set the glyph-orientation-horizontal property on an svg text element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, svg

How do I use javascript to set the glyph-orientation-horizontal property on an svg text element?

I have tried

`svg.setAttribute("style","glyph-orientation-horizontal:90");`
and also tried
`svg.style.glyph-orientation-horizontal=90;`

the first clears all style values so that `style=''`  the second throws a javascript error

svg is defined as
`var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");`

Do I need to individually set the value on all child text elements of the container svg?  Or can I set the value on the container svg and the text elements will inherit that value?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
christopher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyphens turn into camelCase:

```
svg.style.glyphOrientationHorizontal = 90
```

Comment: Ahhh...
Good to know.  Worked perfectly.